# jQuery: Using .ajax() inside of .each()

Tags: jquery

I have a list of RSS links/URLs on a page that I'm attempting to loop through using jQuery's .each functionality. Inside of that loop I am trying to use .ajax functionality to send the link to a php page that will run and then return a 1 for success or a 0 for failure. My .ajax 'success' function will use this 1 or 0 to change the color of the link on the page to green if it was successful and red if it was not.

Below is my code which does not work. What is wrong with it?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#fetch_rss').click(
        function() {

            $('tr.rssrow').each(
                function() {

                    var link = $('a.rsslink', this).attr('feed_link');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "rss_process.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {'link':link},
                        success: function(msg) {
                            if (msg > 1) {
                                $('td.link', this).addClass('green');
                            } else {
                                $('td.link', this).addClass('green');
                            } 

                        },
                        fail: function(msg) {
                            $('td.link', this).addClass('orange');
                        }
                    });

                } // .each callback
            ); // .each
        } // .click callback
    ); // .click

});
```

Comment: I may be wrong but usually you have to pass a string to a 'data' property.

Comment: "feed_link" not an allowed attribute name, so I wonder if that's the problem.  We need to know what kind of problem is occurring.  And posting the HTML along with the Javascript would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this inside the ajax callbacks doesn't refer to the original this.

You should add this to your $.ajax() hash of preferences:

```
context : this
```

See "context" at [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

One other thing that's wrong with your code is that you're frequently using this instead of $(this). For example:

```
var link = $('a.rsslink', this).attr('feed_link');
```

Should be written as:

```
var link = $('a.rsslink', $(this)).attr('feed_link');
```

Same for:

```
$('td.link', this).addClass('green');
```

Should be:

```
$('td.link', $(this)).addClass('green');
```

There are other places where you're doing this too.

One other thing. The following always adds the class "green" to the td.link:

```
if (msg > 1) {
  $('td.link', this).addClass('green');
} else {
  $('td.link', this).addClass('green');
}
```

You should treat the else part with different class (orange?).

Comment: My sincerest 'thank you' for the quick answer to the question, Kristinn! That fixed it. Also, thank you for the tips on using 'this'. I did not know that.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you would mark my answer as the correct one and give it points by clicking the up arrow. :-) Thanks. :-)

Comment: Ha. First post and just learning proper Stack Overflow etiquette. I marked the answer but need 11 more reputation points to be allowed to increment the number. :-)

Comment: Hehe. That's fine. Thank you for that. :-)